# Are all the people except Muslims going to end up in Hell?

Tags: non-muslim, jahannam

What will happen to all the other non Muslim souls after they die? Are they bound to end up in Hell? Or will they have a trail different than ours? Please Explain.

Comment: Just as a short input: That depends on whether they have received the message of Islam etc.

Answer (score 3):

No. Allah won't punish all non-Muslims for their beliefs. Allah almighty, may he be exalted, says in the Quran (interpretation of the meaning):

> Whoever is guided is only guided for [the benefit of] his soul. And
>   whoever errs only errs against it. And no bearer of burdens will bear
>   the burden of another. **And never would We punish until We sent a
>   messenger.** [Qur'an 17:15]

He won't punish the non-Muslims to whom the massage of Islam didn't reach. Those who didn't receive the massage will be **tested again in the hereafter.**
But the non-Muslims who rejected Islam after hearing about it will go to hell. Prophet (peace be upon him) said:

> "By the One in Whose hand is the soul of Muhammad, there is no-one of
>   this ummah, Jew or Christian, **who hears of me then dies without
>   believing in that** with which I have been sent, but he will be one of
>   the people of Hell." (Reported by Muslim, may Allaah have mercy on
>   him, in al-Saheeh, 153).

The Quran says (interpretation of the meaning):

> "And whoever seeks a religion other than Islam, it will never be
>   accepted of him, and in the Hereafter he will be one of the losers."
>   [Qur'an 3:85]

The non-Muslims who know about Islam and reject it and seek another religion other than Islam will go to hell. It's worth noting that Allah won't throw them the directly into hell. They will get a fair trial. Even though they are ungrateful evildoers, Allah will allow them to provide arguments in defence of them.

But there will be **sound and clear evidence against them** and they will accept the judgement of Allah almighty. They will want to come back to earth promising that they will follow all the commands of Allah if they are given another chance. But they won't be given another chance.

Comment: "The non-Muslims who know about Islam and reject it and seek another religion other than Islam will go to hell." What about people who don't seek any religion? Also, what about people who know about Islam but aren't convinced?

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you an answer from some thing with real authority, the Quran!

> *Indeed, those who believed and those who were Jews or Christians or Sabeans [before Prophet Muhammad] - those [among them] who believed in Allah and the Last Day and did righteousness - will have their reward with their Lord, and no fear will there be concerning them, nor will they grieve*

https://quran.com/2:62

So definitely there are a huge group of non-Muslims that won't go to hell.

I also wrote a similar answer before [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/35910/13637)

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Someone (that knows religion more than me) told me that it depends on whether they have received the message of Islam or not (accordingly to the first answer). those who received the message and rejected it will perish in the hell. those who have not received it will be submitted to tests.